# Faile to lookup view even tho everything else is found

Tags: express, routes, passport.js

I am creating a simple `passport-local` sign-in app.

Everything seems to work fine up until I successfully log in.

Specifically, I need to access the `/admin` view which is only seen after a successful login.

this is my **routes/index.js file:**

module.exports = function(app, passport) {

```
    // GET The HOME-page
    app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'Index',
            message: 'Index Page'
        });
    });

    // GET The LOGIN-page
    app.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('login', {
            title: 'Login',
            message: 'Login Page',
            flash_message:  req.flash('loginMessage')
        });
    });


    // Process the login form
    app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/admin',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true 
    }),
    function (req, res) {
        console.log('Hi');
        res.redirect('/');
     });

    app.get('/admin', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
        res.render('/admin', {  <-ERROR IS POINTED HERE
            title: 'Admin',
            message: 'Admin page'
        });
    });

    app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    });
};

// route middleware
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }  <-ERROR IS POINTED HERE
    res.status(403).send('[403] Forbidden');
}
```

I `console.logged` what the `req.isAuthenticated` omits and it omits true, so it Should return `next()`. the page, of course, gives the 500 code so the 403 isn't invoked.

I changed the admin route to another page without the `isLoggedIn` and it worked so my folder structure is set right.
Thus the **isLoggedIn** function is messing something up? But how, and why would it say *Failed to lookup*, I don't quite understand.

Comment: Try to place `isLoggedIn` function before your routes. Before your `// GET The HOME-page`

Comment: Still same error persists, I don't think js compiles code linearly like C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a little debugging, I found it was only a simple / error.

```
 app.get('/admin', isLoggedIn ,function (req, res) {
        res.render('/admin', {
            title: req.user,
            message: 'Admin page'
        });
    });
```

The `res.render('/admin');` had to be changed to `res.render('admin');`

So from this, I could conclude is that `res.render()` has to lookup by name.

As for `app.get('/admin')` sets the route, to put it simply